# How to show and update selected and unselected category in product update page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have theree tables

```
Categories:
    cat_id
    ... other ...
    primary key (cat_id)

Product:
    Product_id
    ... other ...
    primary key (Product_id)

Product_cat:
    Product_id foreign key (post.Product_id)
    cat_id foreign key (Categories.cat_id)
    primary key (category_id,product_id)
```

I have successfully inserted multiple category to a product on create new product page. But I don't understand how to display selected category as well as unselected category on product update page. If i query to Product_cat table it will generate only selected category which was assigned on new product page. Should I query from categories and Product_cat table separately, and store it to an array and merge the two array and display it on update page? One thing more when I update product category how to update it on Product_cat table?

Comment: SO is not a "could you do this for me". What have you done and what didnt work?

Comment: as far I understand, you wish to get all categories data and product_cat table data, you can use **left join** within categories and product_cat, it will get you all records from categories and product_cat. To update product_cat "update product_cat set cat_id= '".$new_id."' where product_id = '".$product_id."'  "

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support, and thanks who voted down my question. Here is my answer-

On controller :

```
<select class="form-control" name="categories[]" multiple>
<?php
    $product_id = "your product id";
    $category = $this->admin_product_model->getAllCat();
    foreach ($category as $row)
    {
        if( $this->admin_product_model->getCatByProductId($product_id,$row->cat_id) ){
            echo '<option value="'.$row->cat_id.'" selected>'.$row->cat_name.'</option>';
        }else{
            echo '<option value="'.$row->cat_id.'">'.$row->cat_name.'</option>';
        }
    }
?>
</select>
```

This is only category select box section where $product_id = "your product id". I just call getAllCat() method from admin_product_model and when display it just check if the category already present on product_category table. If yes then add an attribute selected else show it as it is.

On admin_product_model model:

```
//Get all category
function getAllCat(){
    $query = $this->db->get('category')->result();
    return $query;
}
```

//This method check if product has this category

```
function getCatByProductId($product_id,$cat_id){

    $this->db->from("product_cat");
    $this->db->where('product_id',$product_id);
    $this->db->where('cat_id',$cat_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()>=1){
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }   
}
```

When user select or unselect category and other fields on product update page, the updateProduct method updated the all product related field to product table and check if update successful. If yes then delete all data of product_id from product_cat table and then loop through the $product_categories and insert the new value to product_cat table.

// update product

```
function updateProduct($id,$product_categories)
{

// if all done just update new data to product
$data = array(
    ----your data to update product table----
);

$this->db->where('product_id',$id);
if($this->db->update('product',$data)){

    //Delete existing category
    $this->db->where('product_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('product_cat');

    //store categories like this when user post data "$product_categories = $this->input->post('categories')"
    foreach ((array)$product_categories as $category)
    {
        $pc_data = array(
            'product_id' => $id,
            'cat_id' => $category
        );

        $this->db->insert('product_cat', $pc_data);    
    }
}

return true;
```

}

May be this is not right way but this method worked for me.